# what the usage of Client secret and redirect URI and app in azure b2c and app service

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, token

(1) I am new in azure and OAuth2.  for a native application, The azure b2c need set redirect uri , and the uri can't be a http/https. Does the redirect uri is used to indicate where the native application need to visit after it get the token from azure b2c?
 Does the redirect uri is point to a api/resource which is already pre-set in the native application, thus the b2c tell a uri instead of a url to the native application to avoid otherone know the url and hijack the url?

(2) How the webservice/webapi to verificate whether a token(such as a token provided by a native client) is from the b2c? Do I should Resolve the token by the Client secret from the b2c?

Comment: have you read the b2c documentation? I imagine it is all documented. also you should be able to find b2c samples/tutorials on github

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples

Comment: @Thomas, I have read it but I am not sure whether my understand is right.